# docker error inside jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

i am trying to run docker file from jenkins pipeline, but getting following error:

```
[calculator] Running shell script
+ docker build -t 68b1ea65394fc34128536ce52ef49a0c5b9eac1b -f Dockerfile .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   51.4MB

Step 1/3 : FROM ruby:2.4
 ---> e0e354017c3d
Step 2/3 : ENV COCOAPODS_VERSION 1.4.0
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 89c6fd574e4b
Step 3/3 : RUN gem install cocoapods --version ${COCOAPODS_VERSION}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 71d69d6ad374

Successfully built 71d69d6ad374
Successfully tagged 68b1ea65394fc34128536ce52ef49a0c5b9eac1b:latest
[Pipeline] dockerFingerprintFrom
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:249)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:218)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:929)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:449)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.launch(DockerClient.java:296)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.launch(DockerClient.java:277)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.launch(DockerClient.java:274)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.inspect(DockerClient.java:198)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.inspectRequiredField(DockerClient.java:218)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.FromFingerprintStep$Execution.run(FromFingerprintStep.java:129)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.FromFingerprintStep$Execution.run(FromFingerprintStep.java:85)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

looks like its able to create and tag docker file but not able to run it. not sure, can anyone help / guide me for this error.

Comment: dockerfile contents:

FROM ruby:2.4

ENV COCOAPODS_VERSION 1.4.0

RUN gem install cocoapods --version ${COCOAPODS_VERSION}

Comment: Have you installed and start docker on Jenkins?

Comment: i have installed docker plugins on jenkins.

Comment: have you create Jenkinsfile (Declarative Pipeline) file?

Comment: yes, i have jenkinsfile and dockerfile as well.

Comment: post jenkinsfile code.

Comment: pipeline{
 
 agent { 
  dockerfile true
 }
.....
}

Comment: posted related code from jenkinsfile, it just says that use docker file for docker related setups.

Comment: Have you try to put docker in the path on environment configuration file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171988/discussion-between-matrix-and-haresh-chhelana).